# How to create a "referral" integration in Salesforce?

Tags: integration

It has come to my attention that there are 3 integration levels in Salesforce.

- referral integration
- free listing
- fully integrated

I would like to know more about the "referral" integration.  I'm not entirely sure that I am even using the correct language here. Any guidance or correction in my assumptions are welcome.

Comment: here  you will find all about integration https://www.inkling.com/store/book/integration-architecture-salesforce/

Answer (score 0):

There are five paths to integration in salesforce which are as follows ,

- Native desktop connectors
- AppExchange Marketplace
- Native ERP connectors
- Integration partner ecosystem
- Developer toolkits

For more information on integration architecture, path to integration of salesforce  you can refer to following links in order
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integration
https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/06.2328_WP_ApexConnect_2.pdf
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/11/salesforce-integration-architecture.html